# LightGBM Python API. Best_iteration and best_score for custom evaluation function (feval)

Tags: python-3.x, lightgbm

I'm using lightgbm.train with valid_sets, early_stopping_rounds and feval function for multiclass problem with "objective": "multiclass". I want to find best_iteration and best_score for my custom evaluation function. But it finds them for multi_logloss metrics, which is corresponding to specified objective. So the question is can I find in LightGBM best_iteration and best_score for my feval function and how?

Comment: Please provide some code and read [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the fact that the objective function is included in the list of evaluation metrics by default. Early stopping in LightGBM happens based on **any** included metric. See a short summary and a link to another issue with a longer discussion in [this LightGBM issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1332).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `objective:"multi_error"`, or also you can combine objectives as
`objective: "multi_error", "multi_logloss"`

Multi_error will directly focus on the accuracy.